# how to create multiply li elements with different className

Tags: javascript

I have a problem to add many li elements with different class name, after click button.
There is a code:

js

```
function newLi() {
    return document.createElement("li");
}
 addButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {     

        const ul = document.querySelector(".personListItem")
        ul.appendChild(newLi());
        ul.appendChild(newLi());
        ul.appendChild(newLi());
        ul.appendChild(newLi());

        const className = [
            "nameText", "surnameText", "emailText", "adressText"
        ]
        let li = document.querySelectorAll(".personListItem li")
        li.forEach(e => {
            // here i really dont know what to do. 
        })


    }
});
```

So I need to add this class from className array. Is there any simply solution how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then:

1) You could use the "[index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)" parameter of `forEach` to access the appropriate class from `className` and add it to the `li`. Something like:

```js
const classNames = ["nameText", "surnameText", "emailText", "addressText"];
someLiElements.forEach(function(e,i) {
  e.classList.add(classNames[i]);
})
```

2) To show you another way to get it done, here's a slightly different approach:

```js
function newLiWithClass(className) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add(className);
    return li;
}

const ul = document.querySelector(".personListItem")
["nameText", "surnameText", "emailText", "addressText"].forEach(function(e){
  ul.appendChild(newLiWithClass(e));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that :) This is exactly what I need it :)